# Snakemake SFTP file transfer not running on SLURM worker nodes

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I am using snakemake to run batch workflows in parallel on a SLURM cluster. The input files to the workflow are located on a shared parallel file system, currently everything works as intended, workflow rules are being submitted as individual jobs to the cluster which are then producing the expected results.

However not all the input files I would like to process through the workflow are located on the shared storage but are on a remote server. I would like to use SFTP to copy those files over if they are missing from the local storage. I am able to get SFTP implemented in the workflow but the file downloading is being run serially on the head node instead of on a worker node. This results in a bottleneck when trying to run batch workflows on many input files.

Here is a stripped down snakemake file to copy the file over:

```
from snakemake.remote.SFTP import RemoteProvider as SFTPRemoteProvider

with open(config['data_files']) as f:
    data_files = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

SFTP = SFTPRemoteProvider(username = "xxx")

rule all:
    input:
        expand(f'{config["output_dir"]}/{{line}}_raw',zip, line=data_files),
rule raw:
    input:
        raw = lambda wildcards: SFTP.remote(f'{config["remote_dir"]}/{wildcards.line}_raw')

    output:
        raw = f'{config["output_dir"]}/{{line}}_raw'

    conda:
          transfer_env
    resources: 
          mem_mb= 5000mb,

    threads: 
          1
    shell:
        """
        cp {input.raw} {output.raw}
        """
```

After downloading the file on the head node the shell 'cp' command is being run on the cluster.

Is there a way to execute the download as part of job on the cluster?

I know I can call a custom script in the shell that uses Paramiko to copy the data over but it seems defeat the purpose of having the SFTP functionality.